# Trouble incorporating "Related Articles" block into panel

Tags: blocks, panels, views

I have a "Related Articles" view block that is in use on the site, and it functions fine. The site's original dev team configured everything through templates, but the code is placed in the "Article" template properly, and it all is well. This is a standard Related Articles block that uses the contextual filter "Content: Has taxonomy term ID" to find other nodes of Article type with the same taxonomy terms.

I have a problem, though, creating a similar block for a recently created content type ("News"). This node type's display is configured through Panels, though I'm not sure if that's what's causing the issue. I cloned the original block and altered the (non-contextual) filter to select content based on whether the content type is either Article or News (the original does only Article). Everything else is the same, including the contextual filters. When I place this block in the News panel, I get no results in the block (I've double-checked to make sure I'm using terms that exist on other articles).

I'm sure there are a number of things that could be causing the issue, but I don't know where to look. Can you offer me any guidance?

Thank you.

EDIT:

Here is their php code. I'm not proficient in php, but this looks pretty barebones to me.

```
<?php print '<div class="contextual-links-region panel-pane pane-views pane-slideshow-displays contextual-links-region fusion-block-title-gray-text-red clear"><h2 class="pane-title block-title">Related Stories</h2><div class="pane-content content">' . views_embed_view('related_stories', 'block') . '</div></div>'; ?>
```

EDIT 2:

I have tried placing the following php into the panel:

```
<?php 
$node = menu_get_object();
if (is_object($node)) {
  $tid = $node->field_article_tags['und'][0]['value'];
  $output = views_embed_view('related_articles_for_news_', 'block', $tid);
}
echo $output;
?>
```

Still no luck. Everything looks correct to me. The URL on the view as I edit it is:

admin/structure/views/view/related_articles_for_news_/edit

and this is the only display in the View. The advanced settings say that the machine name is "block", and I confirmed that field_article_tags is correct.

Additionally, I accidentally left off the trailing underscore in the view title originally, and, of course, that did not work either.

Any thoughts as to where I might be going wrong?

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that, your view accepts a Term ID which it uses to get other nodes tagged with the same term. But when you are placing the views block (accepting TID asparameter) in Panels, how are you passing the context to it?

This is probably why your dev went in for the code based approach. I think you can create a custom PHP panels content, grab the node from the present path, then grab the tid from term reference field, and the pass in the tid as context while calling the view through views_embed_view() function.

If you want you can paste the code your dev used and I can help you how you can re use the code in panels to get the same result.

Code Should be something like this:

```
$node = menu_get_object();
if (is_object($node)) {
  $tid = $node->field_yourfieldname['und'][0]['value'];
  $output = views_embed_view('your view name', 'display name', $tid);
}
echo $output;
```

Put the above code in the panel, using a custom content with PHP.

Comment: Ok, so if I understand correctly, even though the block is on the same page, it can't read the tag information from the node? (Adding the other code to OP now)

Comment: updated my answer.

Comment: Still not working. See my second edit. Still getting nothing returned from the php.

Comment: $tid = $node->field_article_tags['und'][0]['value'];

should be 

$tid = $node->field_article_tags['und'][0]['tid'];

This might not be the only error but still you can try that and let me know before i dig further.

Comment: That did it. Thanks very much for the help.

So, to clarify, blocks just can't take contextual information from nodes on their own without it being fed manually via php such at this? How does that original line of code that I pasted in OP work in that case (see my first edit)?

Comment: Glad that helped. I am not sure how that even worked (i mean contextually sensitive) because no context was even passed into that  call. To answer your question, views can take up context by default from limited sources like (nids, tids) but otherwise will need to be passed some other advanced context like this one manually.

And do remember to accept the answer you find correct, so that others can be benefited later.

Comment: Ok, gotcha. Thanks again for your help. I'll try to look into this a little more at some point and see if I can tell how it's working. Maybe the php for that one is somehow contained somewhere else on the template.